# Trying to update firebase but the node value gets deleted

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While running this function, the firebase takes my boolean value but somehow my node name/value is getting deleted. And when I refresh and run it in my simulator again, the data is getting deleted from the simulator but is existing in the firebase. Wondering what went wrong in my code [as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIMSs.png)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
    {

    var x: Bool = false

    let acceptTitle = grocerys[indexPath.row].accepted  ? "Decline" : "Buy"
    let accept = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: acceptTitle) { (action, view, nil) in
        x = !x
        let values = ["accepted": x]
        self.databaseRef?.child(self.grocerys[indexPath.row].id).updateChildValues(values)
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because previously your specific node had a `String` value. But now you are updating that node with a `Dictionary`.

So what's happening here is:

**Previously:**

```
-LDH9D... : "a string"
```

**Now:**

```
-LDH9D... : 
     accepted : true
```

To insert new `Dictionary` type value to a key that had `String` type value, firebase is removing your previously added `String`. Because you can't add to mismatched type.

> But if that node had a `Dictionary` previously, then this update wouldn't delete that data.